# Is there a way to force stream a file to a user's computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, download

I can do the following to force download a CSV file to the client:

```
const response = await fetch(<url>, <options>);
const text = await response.text();
const blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.download = fileName;
anchor.href = url;
anchor.style.display = 'none';

document.body.appendChild(anchor);

anchor.click();
anchor.remove();

URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

This works for moderate sized files, but it is clearly downloading everything into memory before writing to disk. This would surely choke if the file were larger than the amount of available memory on the client. Is there a better method, where `response.body` can be piped directly to the user's filesystem?

**Edit**

To be clear, my goal is to allow very large files to be downloaded, and for all files to be downloaded as efficiently as possible.

Comment: I think there is the 'fs' to read write to the filesystem

Comment: So just write if the right user sends the request?

Comment: @Alex - The fs package only works on the server. The code above is for downloading to the client.

Comment: Hmm writing in the clients file system shouln't be allowed

Comment: @Alex - Writing to the client's chosen downloads folder isn't a problem. They're giving you that permission by coming to your website. You can trigger a download using my code above. I would just like to stream it instead of holding it in memory first.